# Agregar caracter en string en una posicion especifica PHP

Tags: php

hacia tiempo estuve trabajando con números y reconvertirlos en decimales, y perdí el método que lo hacia, `el STR_PAD` rellenan caracteres a la derecha | `NUMBER_FORMAT` lo completa a un formato monetario.

La problema es esto, convertir

```
999 -> 9.99
```

Si alguien tiene el método, es similar al `STR_PAD` pero los datos `($cadena,".",-2)`

Comment: Solo necesitas dividirlo entre 100 y, si necesitas los dos decimales, entonces darle formato: `echo number_format(999/100, 2);`

Answer (score 1):

Como bien dice @Triby, puedes aplicar [**`number_format()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php) al valor dividido entre `100`.

```
$mValue = number_format($mData/100,2);
var_dump ( $mValue );   # string(4) "9.99"
```

Otra manera de hacerlo es con [**`sprintf()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php).

```
$mValue = sprintf('%.2f',  $mData/100);
var_dump ( $mValue );   # string(4) "9.99"
```

---

Si interesa el tipo de dato, puedes hacer un *cast*  a `float`:

```
$mValue = (float) number_format($mData/100,2);
var_dump ( $mValue );   # float(9.99)

$mValue = (float) sprintf('%.2f',  $mData/100);
var_dump ( $mValue );   # float(9.99)
```